# With node-cache module in Node JS, not able to get the data after set

Tags: node.js, caching, node-modules

**Node.js Version: v6.10.3
OS: Windows**

I am trying to implement the caching with Node JS. Using the node-cache module.
I am using below code to set the data into cache and get the data from the cache.

```
const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );

const myCache = new NodeCache( { stdTTL: 3000, checkperiod: 3000} );

obj = { my: "Special", variable: 42 };

myCache.set( "myKey", obj ); // Calling DB, fetch the data and set in to cache for first time when client requests.

value = myCache.get( "myKey" );

console.log('value: ',value);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myCache));
```

But once I set the data, next time when I am trying to get the data (Without setting the data, as I already set it) then it gives me undefined value. When I print the cache I don't see the value (As per below example the value is { my: "Special", variable: 42 }).
So value is not persisted into the cache. I have provided stdTTL as 3000 ms, so data should be available for 3000 ms but it is not available in to cache.

Do I need to set something with TTL or do we have other settings to fetch the saved value in cache?

Comment: It is working fine for me when I tested, can you confirm if you have tested in same session only. Because if you are testing using console and close the session, it will not be saved.

Comment: You would get a value if you are setting an object, string or anything aside from a function. if it is a function, you have to resolve the function and set the result from the function.

Answer (score 0):

just move code to other position

```js
const myCache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 7000, checkperiod: 0 });//here work fine

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    //const myCache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 7000, checkperiod: 0 });// not work
}
)
```